# JQuery Add/Remove Class doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css

I just learned how to use JQuery to make buttons enabling users to change CSS properties. Now I'm trying to create buttons that add or remove CSS classes, using the tutorial at
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp

For some reason, it isn't working. This is the code in my head section:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button#31").click(function(){
 $(".Page1").addClass("georgia nite");
 });
 });
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button#32").click(function(){
 $(".Page1").toggleClass("georgia nite");
 });
 });
</script>

<style>
 .georgia { font-family: Georgia; }
 .nite { background: #000; color: #fff; }
</style>
```

(Page is the name of a class assigned to a div...)

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper" class="Page1">
```

And this is the code in my body section...

```
<button id="btn31">Add Class</button>
<button id="btn32">Toggle</button>
```

For good measure, I also copied the new styles (georgia and nite) into my style sheet. But when I click the "Add Class" or "Toggle" buttons, nothing happens. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have jQuery on the page? Do you see any errors in your browser console? Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) such as a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ids in your HTML and your JS aren't matching.

The correct selector for ids is a `#` followed by the value of the `id` attribute, in your case `$("#btn32")` for `<button id="btn32">`.

Edited JS with changed selector from `button#32` to `#btn32`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btn32").click(function() {
   $(".Page1").toggleClass("georgia nite");
 });
```

Comment: Yikes, I butchered the HTML! I caught the most obvious mistakes in time to modify my original post before I read the responses. Then I learned about my other blooper - not matching the button names. At any rate, it works now. I guess I need a new pair of glasses. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can add multiple classes separated with space? Following code works perfectly for me, however with 1 class only:

```
$('#cl_wind').click(function() {
    $('#_error').addClass('hidden');
});
```

HTML part:

```
<div id="_error">Some text</div>
<button id="cl_wind"></button>
```

UPD: as @dersvenhesse mentioned, id of your element and the one u use in js differes. Elements id cannot be split by char/numbers. It is a single id

Comment: @ lolbas - Actually, you can add multiple classes, separated by a space. I didn't discover that until recently.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom yes, you can add a lot of classes like `class="first second selected etc"`, however id can be only one. You cannot call an element with `id="bttn32"` by `$('#32')` or `$('#bttn')`, only $('#bttn32')` will work